# Two strings are not equal

Tags: java, android, string, equals

I have a Question class with some properties including location name, which is String. I also have a Location class which has some properties and a name method. I want to check if the two are equal, here are some methods and the result:

```
Log.e("", question.getLocation() + ", size:" + question.getLocation().length());
Log.e("", mLocation.getLocationName() + ", size:" + mLocation.getLocationName().length());
Log.e("", "equals: " + question.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase(mLocation.getLocationName()));
Log.e("", "location equals self: " + mLocation.getLocationName().equalsIgnoreCase(mLocation.getLocationName()));
Log.e("", "question location equals self: " + question.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase(question.getLocation()));
```

and here is the log:

```
10-10 19:11:35.618    1893-1893/com.example E/﹕ Machine Room, size:12
10-10 19:11:35.618    1893-1893/com.example E/﹕ Machine Room, size:12
10-10 19:11:35.618    1893-1893/com.example E/﹕ equals: false
10-10 19:11:35.618    1893-1893/com.example E/﹕ location equals self: true
10-10 19:11:35.618    1893-1893/com.example E/﹕ question location equals self: true
```

I have no idea what is happening and why two strings are not equal? Can anyone tell me?

```
public class Question {
   ...
   private String location;

   public String getLocation() {
    return location;
   }

   public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
   }

}

public class Location {
   ...
   private String locationName;

   public String getLocationName() {
     return locationName;
   }

   public void setLocationName(String ln) {
     locationName = ln;
   }
}
```

They have only getters and setters, and they are not modified anywhere else so nothing touches the two words between the logs.

**SOLUTION**

As RC mentioned in the comments:
dump both string as bytes and compare, perhaps the space is not a space on one of the string (alt+0160 produce a space "look-alike" under MSWindows)

Comment: You stated "So I have a Question with some properties and has a location name which is String."  Does the question have a Location object and a locationName property?  If so it's possible that the Location object is displaying it's toString() method when you Log it out but the compare is comparing Location Object to a String Object?

Comment: I asked the above question based on the wording used and the question.getLocation() call.

Comment: @Diver Good point. Although then `equalsIgnoreCase()` would either give `false` when comparing `location` to itself or throw an exception (maybe compile time error).

Comment: I think we might need to see the code of those classes.

Comment: Do `getLocation()` and `getLocationName()` always return the same value on each call?

Comment: Add `.toString().equals(... .toString())`.

Comment: One of those is probably not a `String`

Comment: I have a selected location and around 1000 questions and have to find the questions with the selected location. The strange thing is that before checking for location equality I check for sublocation equality, and that is working and I don't understand how two strings are not equal when they are? Does the String class has encoding or something?

Comment: dump both string as bytes and compare, perhaps the space is not a space on one of the string (alt+0160 produce a space "look-alike" under MSWindows)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I didn't know this.

Answer (score -2):

RC is absolutely right!!!!
Convert String to byte Array by using getBytes() method
Then compare the byte Array Object by using Arrays.equals(Byte[],Byte[]);
This is best posibile solution for this.

Comment: That will not yield different results. Plus, no-arg `getBytes()` is error prone due to system standard encoding possibly not being able to map all java chars and di-chars.